# Heroku: user status banned from creating email addons on apps

Tags: django, heroku, sendgrid, add-on

I **deployed** a **Django** application on **Heroku**, which uses email verification during signup. I wanted to use **Sendgrid addons**, unfortunately I am getting this error:

`Item could not be created....  **User- user status banned**`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a 3rd party support issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `heroku` the issue with `sendgrid`

I have googled regarding this issue, you have to contact to `sendgrid` regarding this issue:

https://support.sendgrid.com/